# How to provide different values for the same object?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to make a simple fishing game. I would like to have the object 'salmon' to be added to inventory more than once with different values for 'weight' and 'resist'. With the inventory.add_item function below, it appears that either only one item is being added to the inventory or the same item is added twice with the same values.

How am I able to get the same type of object with different values?

```
import random

class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fishes = {}

    def add_item(self, fish):
        self.fishes[fish.species] = fish

    def print_items(self):
        print('\t'.join(['Weight', 'Resist', 'Species']))
        for fish in self.fishes.values():
            print('\t'.join([str(x) for x in [fish.weight, fish.resist, fish.species]]))

inventory = Inventory()

class Fish(object):

    def __init__(self, weight, resist, species):

        self.weight = weight
        self.resist = resist
        self.species = species

salmon = Fish(random.randint(2, 10), random.randint(5, 7), 'Atlantic Salmon')

print('Going fishing...\nCaught a Salmon!')

inventory.add_item(Fish(salmon.weight, salmon.resist, salmon.species))
inventory.add_item(Fish(salmon.weight, salmon.resist, salmon.species))

inventory.print_items()
```

Comment: You should consider using a `list` instead of a `dict` to store your fishs. If you really need a `dict` for other reasons, then you should use a `dict` of `list`s, or use other keys to avoid duplicates, for instance `(fish.species, fish.weight, fish.resist)`. You can use every hashable object as a `dict` key, which includes `tuple`s of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 salmon = Fish(random.randint(2, 10), random.randint(5, 7), 'Atlantic Salmon')
 salmon2 = Fish(random.randint(2, 10), random.randint(5, 7), 'Atlantic Salmon2')

 print('Going fishing...\nCaught a Salmon!')

 inventory.add_item(salmon)
 inventory.add_item(salmon2)

 inventory.print_items()
```

First the key for the dictionary must be unique:

```
fish.species
```

also the object you add, because of the key...